# how to use PageView and Bottom Navigator together?

Tags: flutter, widget, bottomnavigationview, flutter-pageview, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want to access `page view` as well as the `bottom navigator` with the same controller so that I can have that page swipe action that page view has by default.

I wanted to link pageview screens to the bottom navigator with the controller to have a swipe page change action. Now I do have to use page view with bottom navigator, but which is linked together with the current index number due to which page swipe transitions fail to execute. now the page changes only when I click the specific page on the bottom navigator.
and i need to reduce the api calling too..
i am using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin as of now

Is there any other way I can get the page swipe transition to sync with the bottom navigator Which can also reduce the api calling??

Code
Scaffold part

```
Scaffold(
                    appBar: ToolbarNavigation(title, CustomColors.colorBlue),
                    body: PageView(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: pageController,
                      onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
                      children: screens,
                    ),
                    /* Bottom Navigator */
                    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
                      selectedItemColor: CustomColors.colorBlue,
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      iconSize: 30,
                      items: [
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Image(
                            image: const AssetImage(Constants.Home),
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          label: 'Home',
                          tooltip: '',
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon:  const AssetImage(Constants. a),
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          label: 'A',
                          tooltip: '',
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Image(
                            image: const AssetImage(Constants. b),
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          label: 'B',
                          tooltip: '',
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Image(
                            image: const AssetImage(Constants.c),
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          label: 'C',
                          tooltip: '',
                        ),

                      ],
                      onTap: (index) {
                        onTabChange(index);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    screens = [
      Home(),
      const A(),
      const B(),
      const C(),
     
    ];
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.pageNumber);
    _currentIndex = widget.pageNumber;
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   
    });
  }
```

OnTabChange & OnPageChange

```
  int _currentIndex = 0;

void onTabChange(index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
    pageController.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please include some code or a picture. Know exactly what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829162/bottom-navigation-bar-design-in-flutter-expand-an-icon-when-its-clicked

Comment: @MobinAnsar Thankyou for this reference but Even after using all the solutions & trying BottomNavyBar plugin too i am missing something by which the page swipe transition is inactive. I am clueless about what's  the small thing going wrong

Comment: Kindly add Error Pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedIndex = 0;
List<Widget> tabList = [
const YouTubeScreen(),
Container(color: Colors.red,),
Container(color: Colors.green,),
];

PageController pageController = PageController();    

Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    currentIndex: selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
    onTap: (index){
      setState(() {
        selectedIndex = index;
      });
      pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    },
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: 
  Icon(Icons.ondemand_video_sharp),label: "Youtube"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: 
  Icon(Icons.video_collection_rounded),label: "Local"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings),label: 
  "Setting")
    ],
  ),
  body: PageView(
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    controller: pageController,
    children: const [
      YouTubeScreen(),
      PipScreen(),
      SettingScreen()
    ],
  )
  // tabList[selectedIndex]
);
```

Use pageview in body and you got what you want
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var _currentIndex = 0;
PageController pageController = PageController();  

itemChaned(index) {
  setState(() {
    _currentIndex = index;
  });
  pageController.jumpToPage(index);
}

Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("PageView and BottmNavigationBar"),
  ),
  body: PageView(
    controller: pageController,
    onPageChanged: itemChaned,
    children: [
      Center(
        child: Text("Home"),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text("Profile"),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text("Settings"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: "Home",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: "Profile",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        label: "Settings",
      )
    ],
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    onTap: itemChaned,
  ),
);
```

You can use `PageView` and `BottomNavigationBar` together. I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if it meets your requirement

`Solution 1`: Using Bottom Navigation Bar

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Red'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        label: 'Blue',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline), label: 'Yellow')
    ];
  }

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Red(),
        Blue(),
        Yellow(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TITLE'),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          bottomTapped(index);
        },
        items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Solution 2`: Without using Bottom Navigation Bar

```
class ImageFullViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageFullViewScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ImageFullViewScreenState createState() => ImageFullViewScreenState();
}

class ImageFullViewScreenState extends State<ImageFullViewScreen> {
  List imagesList = [
    'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50',
    'https://resize.hswstatic.com/u_0/w_480/gif/hybrid-tea-rose-1.jpg',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1368424494/photo/studio-portrait-of-a-cheerful-woman.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=9eszAhNKMRzMHVp4wlmFRak8YyH3rAU8re9HjKA6h3A='
  ];
  int currentPageIndex = 0;
  PageController? pageViewController;
  ValueNotifier<bool> refreshList = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageViewController =
        PageController(initialPage: currentPageIndex, keepPage: true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
        child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
            centerTitle: true,
            titleSpacing: 0.0,
            elevation: 0.0,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                  size: 38,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: pageViewController,
              onPageChanged: (int pageChangeIndex) {
                currentPageIndex = pageChangeIndex;
                refreshList.value = !refreshList.value;
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                currentPageIndex = index;
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0,
                      ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.70,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: InteractiveViewer(
                          child: Image.network(
                        imagesList[currentPageIndex] ?? "",
                        filterQuality: Platform.isIOS
                            ? FilterQuality.medium
                            : FilterQuality.low,
                        loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                            ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                          if (loadingProgress == null) {
                            return child;
                          }
                          return Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                          );
                        },
                        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                          return Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: imagesList.length,
            ),
          ),
          if (imagesList != null &&
              imagesList.isNotEmpty &&
              imagesList.length > 1)
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: refreshList,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 25.0,
                    left: 15.0,
                    right: 15.0,
                    bottom: 5.0,
                  ),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      controller: ScrollController(),
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                      addRepaintBoundaries: false,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int listViewIndex) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            currentPageIndex = listViewIndex;
                            pageViewController?.jumpToPage(currentPageIndex);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: 20.0,
                            width: 55.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(4.0),
                              ),
                              border: Border.fromBorderSide(
                                BorderSide(
                                  color: currentPageIndex == listViewIndex
                                      ? Colors.white
                                      : Colors.black38,
                                  width: 2.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: currentPageIndex != listViewIndex
                                  ? const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0))
                                  : const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(0.0)),
                              child: InteractiveViewer(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  imagesList[listViewIndex] ?? "",
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  height: 40.0,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  filterQuality: Platform.isIOS
                                      ? FilterQuality.medium
                                      : FilterQuality.low,
                                  loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                      Widget child,
                                      ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                                    if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                      return child;
                                    }
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 40.0,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 40.0,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      color: Colors.grey[300]!,
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                        // );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: imagesList.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for you efforts, Even after using all the solutions i am missing something by which the page swipe transition is inactive. I am clueless about what's  the small thing going wrong